# AWS DynamoDB - sync localhost db with server hosted db?

Tags: android, database, amazon-web-services, localhost, amazon-dynamodb

I'm very new to working with databases in general! I'm working with DynamoDB for a mobile app and I recently discovered that I could use Python to script table creation and data entry by running DynamoDB locally on my computer. Now, intuitively, I thought there must be a way to test my database and locally, but then push the changes to my server hosted DB. But after countless searches on Google, I still can't find a way to do so and it doesn't seem like this concept exists?

Can anyone fill in the blanks for me here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [DynamoDBLocal](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html) for testing your changes? 
If so, DynamoDBLocal is meant to be a standalone application purely for offline testing. There is no way or mechanism to sync the changes to the local database to the API hosted service.